# Relative Mouse only on Chrome Remote Desktop with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, mouse

I'm currently running Ubuntu + XFCE VM's, and accessing them with Chrome Remote Desktop.
Until recently (last week or so?) everything worked great, but now in new VMs, mouse clicks only work with "relative mouse" turned on in the client.  I would really like to use "absolute" movement, as it appears more performant to the users.

On the server/VM `lsinput` shows only 2 power buttons, a keyboard, and a "PS/2" mouse.  It does not show a touchscreen device, which I would expect to see for "absolute" mouse movement.

How do I get Remote Desktop working without relative movement, or start to diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed `chrome-remote-desktop` was being held back from being upgraded (I don't know why).
I was able to upgrade it using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt satisfy "chrome-remote-desktop (>= 122)" -y
```

and this seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: great, it worked!

Comment: It really helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone else runs into this issue:

Currently `https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb` downloads version `120.0.6099.24`. No idea why.

It looks like this version is buggy.

I tried using `chrome-remote-desktop_114.0.5735.35_amd64.deb` and `chrome-remote-desktop_122.0.6261.0_amd64.deb` from this mirror:

`https://deb.rug.nl/ppa/mirror/dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb/pool/main/c/chrome-remote-desktop/`

Both version worked fine.

Solution suggested by `bkanuka` (`sudo apt satisfy "chrome-remote-desktop (>= 122)"`) probably needs an extra step to configure APT repository.